# Concept of array in Reactivex

Tags: c#, arrays, reactive-programming, reactivex

Hi I'm starting to use ReactiveX c#, all sounds good, except for a concept.

I dunno how to make a reactive array ( or collection or list)

I'd like to have something like ObservableCollection, but with concept of reactive.
I would mean that no one of members of array is reactive, but is the array itself that is reactive, just like Observable collection.

I don't understand how can make this possible if all in a reactive is just a stream...

So the question is what's interface or object I should use to get a reactive array?

Thanks

Comment: Something of type `IObservable<IEnumerable<A>>` perhaps?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The Right way to create ObservableCollection but using ReactiveX in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are searching for something like an ObservableCollection powered with ReactiveX take a look on http://www.reactiveui.net. It is a MVVM Framework on top of ReactiveX.

There is a ReactiveList which provides you observables for ItemsAdded, ItemsRemoved, Count, Changed and some more. And implements INotifyCollectionChanged as well.

Look at the doku: https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/275eca3dc2e5fc93bddb137e60be32885f788688/docs/basics/reactive-list.md

Don't hesitate to ask me if you have further questions.